# Bounded function with parameter

Tags: functions, continuity

Let f be defined $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is continous and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a=-\infty$ or $b=\infty$, is the function bounded?

I do not know how to figure this out, detailes and help here are necessary.

Comment: If $\;a,b\in\Bbb R\;$ then it can't be $\;a,b=\pm\infty\;$

Comment: But what if we will skip this condition? This question must be a bit more sophisticated.

Comment: Still your question makes no sense: what does "...for $\;a=-\infty\,,\,\,b=\infty\;$ must be bounded function?" mean, anyway?

Comment: By bounded function i mean what is on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function) thus whether for those values this function must be bounded

Comment: ""Must""?? Why "must"? Perhaps you mean "can"? Then yes: there are continuous functions which *can* be bounded on $\;(-\infty,\infty)\;$ , for example constant ones.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f: (-\infty,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R: x \mapsto x^2$. It's continuous but not bounded. So the answer to your question is "no".

But you can show the following: Take a continuous function $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $a,b\in\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ and $a<b$. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow b}f(x)$ exists, then $f$ is bounded.